# Update Project as Git in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

I had a Maven project. It was not a git project initially. After completing the project I pushed it to a Git repo using Git Bash in Windows. Now I wanted to update my current project as Git project so that I can directly push changes onto my repo from Eclipse itself.

What do I do to update my project as a Git project in Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option [Team > Share Project](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-61f_syncproject.htm) for your existing Eclipse project (meaning your project is already visible in your Eclipse workspace).

[image: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/Image82_repo_sync1.png]

Using an "existing project", Eclipse will recognize your Git repository.

Answer (score 1):

1. You might have to install **EGit** plugins
2. Open the view **Git Repositories**
3. On the toolbar of this view, you have 2 buttons: *Add an existing local Git Repository* or *Clone a Git Repository*.

[image]

3. The cloned Git Repositories are then shown in the view
4. Right click on the one you want and choose **Import Projects** menu item to import projects you want to work on into your workspace.

[image]

5. After making changes to imported projects, you can open the view **Git Staging** to stage and commit those changes to the git repository.

[image]

For more details, you can check out the **Egit Documentation** in the **Help Contents** of Eclipse or [online here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide)